# How to I go to the next page after login request - python

Tags: python, http, python-requests

i am trying to go to `http://192.168.1.235/status.cgi` after logging into the website. I am unsure of how to do this. As can be seen below in my code, i tried to access the next page immediately after I logged in, however this results in a redirect to the login page.

```
import  requests
#login
payload = {'password': "password"}
netGearSiteLogin = requests.post("http://192.168.1.235/login.cgi",params=payload)
netGearSitePortStatus = requests.get("http://192.168.1.235/status.cgi")
print(netGearSitePortStatus.text)
```

**Results**

```
<head>
<title>Redirect to Login</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function RedirectToLoginPage()
{
    top.location.href = "/login.cgi";
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="RedirectToLoginPage();">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by using `Sessions`:

```
import  requests
#login
payload = {'password': "password"}
netGearSiteLogin = requests.post("http://192.168.1.235/login.cgi",data=payload,allow_redirects=True)
with requests.Session() as session:
    post = session.post("http://192.168.1.235/login.cgi", data=payload)
    r = session.get("http://192.168.1.235/status.cgi")
    print(r.text)   #or whatever else you want to do with the request data!
```